# Posição do label no Picker do React Native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, combobox

Estou utilizando o componente `Picker` do React Native e ta funcionando, listando, selecionando e tal, só que não consigo estilizar bem ele, consegui colocar borda, arrumar o tamanho porem o texto que fica dentro dele eu não consegui mexer, nem no tamanho da fonte e nem a posição que ele vai ficar la dentro, tentei colocar as propriedades

```
flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
```

no `style` de uma `View` que fica sobre o `Picker`, no `style` do `Picker` e na propriedade `itemStyle` do `Picker` e nenhum destes funcionou, em todos o texto fica na esquerda, não colado, mas fica pra esquerda e eu queria centralizar ele. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código:

```
<View style={HorariosCommandStyles.containerPickerServicos}>
    <Picker itemStyle={{ paddingLeft: 50, fontSize: 35 }} style={{ width: '90%', height: '100%' }}>
        {this.state.servicos.map(s => <Picker.Item label={s.servico.nome} value={s.servico.id} key={s.id} />)}
    </Picker>
</View>
```

Comment: Como você deseja que fique? Coloque o código completo, com os serviços.

Comment: @sant0will Como eu dize na pergunta eu gostaria de centralizar o texto no meio do `Picker` mas em geral seria como estilizar aquele texto do `Picker`.

Answer (score -1):

Boa! Sempre mudo somente a cor do texto dos itens, e é no style do picker. 
Tente lá alterar a centralização.

```
<Picker
    style={styles.txtPicker}
...

</Picker>


txtPicker:{
        color:'#ff0000',
        textAlign:'center',
    },
```

Comment: O style do `Picker` nn é pra estilizar texto, e eu ja tinha tentado isso, mas vlw msmo assim, alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: boa! já fez o teste? pois é assim que funciona aqui. 
Obs: com a cor, com o alinhamento, já não sei.

Comment: Eu ja tinha testado antes mas tbm testei quando vi a sua resposta e ele da um erro dizendo q a propriedade `textAlign` nn se aplica a esse tipo de estilização, tem estilização para componentes e estilização para texto, e o `textAlign` é uma propriedade para estilização de texto sendo que o `style` do `Picker` recebe estilização para componentes